# Android AsyncTask get blocks doInBackground

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I am doing an AsyncTask .If I do a get, the doInBackground never execute it.

my code:

```
private boolean registroServidor(String usuario, String regId, String pass)
{
    Toast toast1;

    context = getApplicationContext();

    mAuthTask=new UserLoginTask();
    mAuthTask.execute();

    try {
        if(!mAuthTask.get(5000,TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)){
            toast1=Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Error al conectarse", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast1.show();
            return false;
        }else{
            toast1=Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"bien conectado", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast1.show();
            conectado=true;
            mAuthTask.cancel(true);
            return true;
        }
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    } catch (ExecutionException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    } catch (TimeoutException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }

}
```

and

```
public class UserLoginTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> {
    private GestorCredencial credenciales = null;



    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
        this.credenciales=new GestorCredencial(user,pass);
        boolean res=credenciales.enviar();
        return res;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

    }



    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(final Boolean success) {
        mAuthTask = null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCancelled() {
        mAuthTask = null;
    }


}
```

LOGCAT

```
08-05 17:12:53.843: W/System.err(3292): java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
08-05 17:12:53.882: W/System.err(3292):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:173)
08-05 17:12:53.883: W/System.err(3292):     at android.os.AsyncTask.get(AsyncTask.java:502)
08-05 17:12:53.883: W/System.err(3292):     at com.laguna.talkme.gui.GUIPanelPrincipal.registroServidor(GUIPanelPrincipal.java:617)
08-05 17:12:53.883: W/System.err(3292):     at com.laguna.talkme.gui.GUIPanelPrincipal.access$11(GUIPanelPrincipal.java:605)
08-05 17:12:53.885: W/System.err(3292):     at com.laguna.talkme.gui.GUIPanelPrincipal$TareaRegistroGCM.doInBackground(GUIPanelPrincipal.java:571)
08-05 17:12:53.885: W/System.err(3292):     at com.laguna.talkme.gui.GUIPanelPrincipal$TareaRegistroGCM.doInBackground(GUIPanelPrincipal.java:1)
08-05 17:12:53.885: W/System.err(3292):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
08-05 17:12:53.885: W/System.err(3292):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
08-05 17:12:53.885: W/System.err(3292):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
08-05 17:12:53.885: W/System.err(3292):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
08-05 17:12:53.885: W/System.err(3292):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
08-05 17:12:53.885: W/System.err(3292):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:838)
```

The problem: I do execute(), and I debug,then it run the onpreExecute, but, not doinBackground(). When the 5 seconds time out run doinbackground. ANd I get a TimeException :S

Any suggestion??

thanks and sorry for my bad English

Comment: I need do it in asynctask because is a network process.

Comment: and I need to wait the result because I need it

Comment: you must wait the other way around :) it's a common pattern: if you want to block the user interaction, deactivate the screen and/or show some "please wait..." hint. 
When you task is ready, it calls `onPostExecute()` where you activate the screen and/or hide your "please wait..."

Comment: if you do it your way, you will get punished by android with an exception "don't block the main thread"

Comment: no, I dont want block the user iteraction, I want that the code wait to the asynctask is finished

Comment: if you wait by calling `get()` you do block the UI thread

Comment: and how can I do without block it?

Comment: I need to login in a server

Comment: I found the problem. I was calling it since another asynctask

Answer (score 0):

try putting the following  code inside onPostExecute() and see if it works..

```
  try {
         if(!mAuthTask.get(5000,TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)){
             toast1=Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Error al conectarse", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
             toast1.show();
             return false;
         }else{
             toast1=Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"bien conectado", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
             toast1.show();
             conectado=true;
             mAuthTask.cancel(true);
             return true;
         }
     } catch (InterruptedException e) {

         e.printStackTrace();
         return false;
     } catch (ExecutionException e) {

         e.printStackTrace();
         return false;
     } catch (TimeoutException e) {

         e.printStackTrace();
         return false;
     }
```

Instead of doing `mAuthTask.get(5000,TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)` use **'success'** parameter of `onPostExecute()`

Comment: I can't write boolean as type in onpostExecute. It have to be void :S

Comment: but in the code I cna see boolean variable-
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(final Boolean success) {
        mAuthTask = null;
    }

Answer (score 0):

By default `AsyncTask`s are executed sequentially in a special thread. In order to make the execution parallel, you need to use:

```
new UserLoginTask().executeOnExecutor( AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR );
```

UPDATE:

You shouldn't call `get()`, as it ruins the whole async-pattern.

This line

> this.credenciales=new GestorCredencial(user,pass);

should be put in the constructor

Comment: it never enter in doInBackground.

Comment: only enter in doInBackground when the get time is out

Comment: I put this in constructor. Similar UU :)

Comment: I assume, you put a breakpoint onto the 1st line of `doInBackground()`. If it is not reached, the problem must have occured before: either in the `preExecute()` or in the constructor, or in the calling code. Put enough breakpoints into those places and see what happens

Comment: it do the onPreExecute, but it is empty :S I tried with  super.onPreExecute(); and it is similar :S

Comment: throw `onPreExcecute()` away completely. as it does nothing as well as the parent clas